# cannot read property 'force_children' of undefined om alpha26

Tags: clojurescript, om

My app was working correctly until I decided to upgrade to om-alpha26. 
Now I'm getting: Cannot read property 'force_children' of undefined

I have tried deleting my target folder and executing 'lein clean' to no avail.

Nothing comes up on google, I made no other code changes apart form updating the om version in my project.clj. I'm using chestnut as my development environment.

Here's my project.clj:

```
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]

  :test-paths ["test/clj"]

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.145" :scope "provided"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]
                 [slester/ring-browser-caching "0.1.1"]
                 [bk/ring-gzip "0.1.1"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [enlive "1.1.6"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha26"]
                 [environ "1.0.0"]

                 [com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.5327"]
                 [liberator "0.13"]
                 [cljs-ajax "0.5.1"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
                 [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient "4.3.5"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [overtone/at-at "1.2.0"]

                 [com.cognitect/transit-clj "0.8.281"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.225"]
                 [com.stuartsierra/component "0.2.3"]

                 [http-kit "2.1.19"]
                 [com.taoensso/sente "1.6.0"]

                 [reaver "0.1.2"]
                 [clj-time "0.11.0"]
                 [differ "0.2.1"]

                 ]

  :repositories [["my.datomic.com" {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"
                                    :username ["******"]
                                    :password ["****"]}]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.5"]
            [lein-environ "1.0.0"]
            [lein-auto "0.1.2"]]

  :min-lein-version "2.5.0"

  :uberjar-name "ngbc.jar"

  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src/cljs"]
                             :compiler {:output-to     "resources/public/js/app.js"
                                        :output-dir    "resources/public/js/out"
                                        :source-map    "resources/public/js/out.js.map"
                                        :preamble      ["react/react.min.js"]
                                        :optimizations :none
                                        :pretty-print  true}}}}

  :profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["env/dev/clj"]
                   :test-paths ["test/clj"]

                   :dependencies [[figwheel "0.3.9"]
                                  [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.0-2"]
                                  [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]
                                  [weasel "0.7.0"]]

                   :repl-options {:init-ns ngbc.server
                                  :nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}

                   :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.3.9"]]

                   :figwheel {:http-server-root "public"
                              :server-port 3449
                              :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
                              :ring-handler ngbc.server/http-handler}

                   :env {:is-dev true
                         :browser-caching {"text/javascript" 0
                                           "text/html" 0}}

                   :cljsbuild {:test-commands { "test" ["phantomjs" "env/test/js/unit-test.js" "env/test/unit-test.html"] }
                               :builds {:app {:source-paths ["env/dev/cljs"]}
                                        :test {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "test/cljs"]
                                               :compiler {:output-to     "resources/public/js/app_test.js"
                                                          :output-dir    "resources/public/js/test"
                                                          :source-map    "resources/public/js/test.js.map"
                                                          :preamble      ["react/react.min.js"]
                                                          :optimizations :whitespace
                                                          :pretty-print  false}
                                               :notify-command  ["phantomjs" "bin/speclj" "resources/public/js/app_test.js"]
                                               }}}}

             :uberjar {:source-paths ["env/prod/clj"]
                       :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
                       :env {:production true
                             :browser-caching {"text/javascript" 604800
                                               "text/html" 0}}
                       :omit-source true
                       :aot :all
                       :main ngbc.server
                       :cljsbuild {:builds {:app
                                            {:source-paths ["env/prod/cljs"]
                                             :compiler
                                             {:optimizations :whitespace
                                              :pretty-print false}}}}}})
```

UPDATE:

The 'force_children' function is not one that I've defined. Following the stack trace it looks like it is being called on a (om.dom/div ....children). When I remove child nodes from the expression the code compiles, here's the code:

```
(defui RootView
       static om/IQuery
       (query [this]
              (let [bonus-subquery (om/get-query Bonus)]
                `[{:bonuses ~bonus-subquery}]))
       Object
       (render [this]
               (let [{:keys [bonuses]} (om/props this)]

                 (dom/div nil <--- ERROR OCCURS HERE


                          (dom/header nil
                                      (dom/div #js {:className "search-header"}
                                               (dom/a #js {:className "logo"})))

                          (dom/ul #js {:className "simple-sidebar"}
                                  (dom/li nil
                                          (dom/div #js {:className "fa fa-gift"})))

                          (dom/div #js {:className "row no-margin main-container"}
                                   (dom/div #js {:className "col-xs-12 no-padding"}
                                            (dom/div #js {:className "artist-songs-container"}

                                                     #_(dom/input nil "Title")
                                                     #_(dom/input nil "Bonus")

                                                     (dom/h6 nil "My Bonuses")

                                                     (apply dom/div nil
                                                            [(dom/h3 nil "Collect")
                                                             (bonus-list-view
                                                               (sort-by-posted bonuses))]))))))))
```

I suspect it is to do with chestnut because the error doesn't occur when I upload the code to heroku. Here's the stack trace:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'force_children' of
>     undefined(anonymous function) @
>     core.cljs?rel=1450501232093:143
>
>ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrCont>ext@react.inc.js:5933
>
>ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent
>     @ react.inc.js:5953
>
wrapper @react.inc.js:12336
>
>ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @
>     react.inc.js:5566
>
>wrapper @
>     react.inc.js:12336
>
>ReactReconciler.mountComponent @
>     react.inc.js:12961
>
>ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @
>     react.inc.js:5571
>
>wrapper @
>     react.inc.js:12336
>
>ReactReconciler.mountComponent @
>     react.inc.js:12961

>
>mountComponentIntoNode @
>     react.inc.js:10854
>
>Mixin.perform @
>     react.inc.js:15613
>
>batchedMountComponentIntoNode @
>     react.inc.js:10870
>
>Mixin.perform @
>     react.inc.js:15613
>
>ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @
>     react.inc.js:8443
>
>batchedUpdates @
>     react.inc.js:13689
>
>ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent @
>     react.inc.js:11064
>
>wrapper @
>     react.inc.js:12336
>
>ReactMount._renderSubtreeIntoContainer @
>     react.inc.js:11133
>
>ReactMount.render @ react.inc.js:11153wrapper @
>     react.inc.js:12336
>
>(anonymous function) @
>     next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:1236
>
>(anonymous function) @
>     next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:1079
>
>(anonymous function) @
>     next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:1090
>
>om.next.Reconciler.om$next$protocols$IReconciler$add_root_BANG_$arity$4
>     @ next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:1111
>
>om$next$protocols$add_root_BANG_ @
>     protocols.cljs?rel=1447028869504:13
>
>om.next.add_root_BANG_.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$4
>     @ next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:660
>
>om$next$add_root_BANG_ @
>     next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:647
>
>om.next.add_root_BANG_.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3
>     @ next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:654
>
>om$next$add_root_BANG_ @
>     next.cljs?rel=1447028869174:647
>
>ngbc$core$main @
>     core.cljs?rel=1450501232093:240
>
>(anonymous function) @
>     main.cljs?rel=1448073424172:14 
>
>core.cljs?rel=1447680439306:164
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a function `force-children`? What is it called on? With the amount of information you provide people can only guess. Also you might want to try to remove the `:preamble` lines. They're not needed as Om depends on `cljsjs/react`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinKlepsch. I've expanded on the question. I tried removing the react preambles but still no joy.